# Need guidance for send and receive SOAP XML messages over IBM MQ using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, soap, ibm-mq

I nearly read everything about IBM MQ and still didn't understand how to send and receive SOAP messages, I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: No different than sending any other message.   A string message is a string message.   SOAP is just a format like JSON or XML, in fact SOAP is represented as XML.

Comment: XML is basically text. So create a Bytes or Text message and put your XML as message body.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, Of course, this is first thing I tried, but it's ok only for "ConvertAndSend" but not working if I used "SendAndRecieve"....'MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED', I'll post the code if it helps

Comment: Message res = jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive("CMS.IN", messageCreator -> {
    TextMessage message = messageCreator.createTextMessage(messageStr);
    return message;
   });

Comment: Error :
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').